# Is there a way to decipher Prof. Goopton's language using in-game cues

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

Are there hints in the game to decrypt his characters to our alphabet?

I.e. by our own observation and without (Spoiler):

> Without using the Sponge

[image]

Comment: This looks like a monoalphabetic cipher (i.e. one symbol for each letter of the alphabet), so you can give [frequential analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis) a try. If this is the only message he says to you, frequential analysis is gonna be tough because you need the largest corpus possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no in-game cues to help translate what he says. (Except the item you mentioned)

If you want to translate it yourself:

> He speaks [Alienese](http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Alienese), a language from futurama